# battery from laptop does only work when power cord is plugged in

Tags: power-management, shutdown, asus, battery

I'm using a Asus laptop, about three years old and since I Switched to Ubuntu (16.04) it shows that the battery is fully charched, but when I disconnect the power cord, the laptop turns off. I can't start it up without first connect the power cord.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly sounds like the battery is dead.  If the laptop won't power on at all until the AC is plugged in I'd blame the battery.